# Comparing to array list through there given index but its returning null exception at file initialization

Tags: arraylist

```
package adc;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Result {

/*
 * Complete the 'sockMerchant' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER n
 *  2. INTEGER_ARRAY ar
 */

public static int sockMerchant(int n, List<Integer> ar) {
// Write your code here
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        if(ar.get(i)==ar.get(j)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    
}
return(count);

}

}

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      '       BufferedWriter(newFileWriter(System.getenv("F:\\")));'

    int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

    String[] arTemp = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

    List<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arTemp[i]);
        ar.add(arItem);
    }

    int result = Result.sockMerchant(n, ar);

    bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
    bufferedWriter.newLine();

    bufferedReader.close();
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
}
```

**Working of code**

> here inputs are n("number of integer arraylist have")=9
> and ar input of arraylist [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
> ** In this ar arraylist we have to find the even pair of number and return the number of pair .**
> *In this example the output is 3.*

Comment: In main method, for BufferedWriter, there is nothing after new.  it should be something like, `BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(..);`

Comment: Yes sir i have updated still same issue

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getenv_string.htm

Comment: have you checked System.getenv?  I think the reason for null pointer exception is that, the value you gave inside `System.getenv()` is not in the environment variables.

Comment: before running the program, run the following command in CMD: set OUTPUT_PATH="path of output folder" and then try running the code.

Comment: Tried as you said but null pointer exception is observed again .